# Mostrar e ocultar div ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de ao clicar no botão iniciar teste, aparecesse a div contador, e ao clicar em proximo teste, sumisse a div id=01 e apenas mostrasse a id=02 e assim por diante, sempre quando clico em próximo teste ele escreve um texto abaixo do outro.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TESTE DO FREIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/botao.css">

    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="contador"></div>
<label id="counter">0</label>
<div id="teste"></div>
<a class="meubotao" onclick="showDivcontador()">INICIAR TESTE</a>
<div class=testes>
  <div align="center" id="01">1. Pressione e solte o pedal<br /> de freio do<br /> estacionamento várias<br /> vezes para checar se a<br /> pressão diminuiu.</div>
  <div align="center" id="02">2. Pressione e solte o pedal de freio do estacionamento varias vezes para checar se a pressão diminui</div>
  <div align="center" id="03">3. Pressione e solte o pedal de freio do estacionamento varias vezes para checar se a pressão diminui</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
&copy; 2017 PokaYoke Team | Elaborado por Felipe Deolindo
</div>



<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

estilos.css

```
body{
    background-color: #373435;
}

#teste{
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.footer {
    position:absolute;
        top: 1080px;
        left: 800px;
}

.testes div {
  display: none;
}

.testes {
    font: arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 120px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    align: center;
}

#counter {
    display: none;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: black;
}

#contador {
   width: 230px; 
   height: 80px;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 900px;
   left: 650px;
   border-left: 10px solid red;
   border-right: 10px solid red;
   border-bottom: 10px solid red;
   border-top: 10px solid red;
   display: none;
}
```

botão.css

```
.meubotao {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    border:3px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
        top: 500px;
        left: 700px;
}
.meubotao:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}
.meubotao:active {
        position:absolute;
        top: 500px;
        left: 700px;
}

.proxEtapa { 
  display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#242124));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #242124);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #242124);
    text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 0px;
    font: normal normal bold 32px arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:980px;
    left:1580px;
}
.proxEtapa:hover,
.proxEtapa:focus {
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#2b282b));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #2b282b);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #2b282b);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:absolute;
}
.proxEtapa:active {
    background: #999999;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#999999), to(#242124));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #242124);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999999, #242124);
    position:absolute;
    top:980px;
    left:1580px;
}
.proxEtapa:after{
    content:  "\0000a0";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 -4px -6px 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 8px;
    background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAeUlEQVRIie2UywqAIBQFh/K7b+R/h2008IEU3bOqAfGxcPTgFX7E7MCiFKQskQqkkkQt6eIKgAErcOS1p+OC5X6bncKjdXF5C7q4FILrJqG9jiMG4iIpSCNSCaqXJN08APFulgOsmUcGhfaGaYF5CqSfnfS7lm7+EU7SAZmTEL6ONwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat left center transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:980px;
    left:1580px;
}
```

e o script.js

```
var testCounter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = '';
    var testEnabled = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
      sensorValor = $('#counter').text();
    }, 100);

    $(".meubotao").click(function(e){
      var len = $('.testes div').length;
      if (len > testCounter){
        $('.testes div').eq(testCounter).show();
        testCounter++;
        if (len == testCounter){
          $('.meubotao').hide(); //ultima etapa ja chegou
        } else {
          $('.meubotao').html('Próxima Etapa');
          $('.meubotao').addClass('proxEtapa');
        }
      }
    });
      function showDivcontador(){
      document.getElementById("meubotao").style.display = 'block';
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo na parte do javascript coloque isso, se o botão ja tiver passado da div antiga, oculta a antiga ou seja testCounter - 1, Testei e funcionou, segue o js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5f0tmw0j/2/

```
var testCounter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = '';
    var testEnabled = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;
    var contaBotao = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
      sensorValor = $('#counter').text();
    }, 100);

    $(".meubotao").click(function(e){

      var len = $('.testes div').length;

      //Se for a primeira vez ele é 0 então não entrará, mas na segunda vez 
       ele entra no if e pega a div anterior "testCounter-1"
      if (len > testCounter){
        if(contaBotao > 0){
            $('.testes div').eq(testCounter-1).hide();
        }
        contaBotao++;
        $('.testes div').eq(testCounter).show();
        testCounter++;
        if (len == testCounter){
          $('.meubotao').hide(); //ultima etapa ja chegou
        } else {
          $('.meubotao').html('Próxima Etapa');
          $('.meubotao').addClass('proxEtapa');
        }

      }
    });
      function showDivcontador(){
      document.getElementById("meubotao").style.display = 'block';
      }
});
```

Comment: Valeu cara, foi certinhoooo

Comment: Disponha @FelipeDeolindo

Comment: Aproveitando mais uma duvida, tem uma forma geometrica desenhada que está em hide, quando eu clicar em iniciar teste eu queria que ela aparecesse, utilizo mais ou menos o mesmo contexto ?

Comment: Sim, mantenha ela hide, quando fizer o primeiro click da um show nela,  $('iddela').show();, mas não entendi muito o objetivo, é uma figura geometrica diferente para cada passo? @FelipeDeolindo

Comment: não anderson, uma apenas, porem ná pagina principal ela não pode aparecer somente nas outras, vou tentar dessa maneira que disse

Comment: Simples, coloque isso que falei dentro do if (contaBotao > 0) que ela só aparecerá nas outras e não na principal @FelipeDeolindo

Comment: valeu Cara, obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem sem código então criei esse exemplo me baseando na pergunta. Qualquer dúvida só usar os comentários, tente adequar o seu código com esse meu algorítimo.

```js
var testeAtual = 0;
$('#btIniciarTeste').click(function(){
  if(this.value === 'Iniciar Teste'){
    this.value = 'Proximo Teste';
  }
  if(this.value === 'Finalizar'){
    window.location.reload();
  }
  
  
  $('.container-teste').find('div').hide();
  $($('.container-teste').find('div')[testeAtual]).show();
  
  if(!$('.container-teste').find('div')[testeAtual]){
    $('#btIniciarTeste').val('Finalizar');
  }
  
  
  
  testeAtual++;
});
```

```css
.container-teste > div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Iniciar Teste" id="btIniciarTeste">
<div class="container-teste">
  <div>O que é JavaScript ? </div>
  <div>O que é PHP ?</div>
  <div>O que é Java ?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, eu coloquei o codigo no fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5f0tmw0j/ , se você puder dar uma analisada , quando clicar no iniciar teste ele escreve a div 01 porem ao clicar no proximo ele escreve a 02 em baixo da 01

Comment: Vou analisar e retorno aqui com a solução.

Comment: Mateus deu certo, consegui usar o seu e ficou perfeito aqui, agora outra duvida, eu coloquei um botão em css, como eu troco ele por uma class usando seu codigo, ao clicar em iniciar teste mudar a formatação dele por add class

Comment: Você pode usar o 'toggleClass' do jQuery ou simplesmente usar o 'removeClass' e depois o 'addClass'  ambos do jQuery. Se minha resposta respondeu sua pergunta não esqueça de marca-la , até a proxima.